# Display Image from SD card using Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on app where i need to download image from local using phonegap file api and then display it in application on various pages.I am using phonegap build not eclipse for build my application.

I have successfully downloaded images to SD card and display image in my pages like " `file:///sdcard/project/promotion/promotion.jpg"` 
but it is not working properly. On some pages it works and some pages it doesn't work. I have checking path by alert and path is fine. I have checked the path by opening in browser and it works fine.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Any error from LogCat ?

Comment: No error comes in logcat....